# "SetCertificatePath" Option in C# iot device client

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-edge

The [Java Azure Iot Device Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.deviceclient?view=azure-java-stable) has the "SetCertificatePath" option to add the root ca certificate in java code so that devices with symmetric key attestation can **validate the gateway device**.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceClient;
...

client = new DeviceClient("HostName=xxx-dev-westeurope.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=demo-source-1;SharedAccessKey=xxx;GatewayHostName=demo-edge.dev.example.com",IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT);          
client.setOption("SetCertificatePath", "C:\\certs\\device_ca_aliasazxVrrdEVxd7kvKvne1pOEyuSHF8EXSowNDhMzl30jI_.cert.pem");
client.open();
```

Is there a similar option in the C# Device Client, like `client.setOption("SetCertificatePath",...)`?

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
...

var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString("HostName=xxx-dev-westeurope.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=demo-source-1;SharedAccessKey=xxx;GatewayHostName=demo-edge.dev.example.com", TransportType.Mqtt);
await deviceClient.OpenAsync();
```

With this code I get an invalid certifacte error:

```
AuthenticationException: TLS authentication error.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.)
```

Does the [C# Azure Iot Device Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient?view=azure-dotnet) have a similar option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# client picks up CA certificates from the local system's Trusted Root Certificate Authority store.

Be sure to use the root certificate, something like: `edge_owner_azxVrrdEVxd7kvKvne1pOEyuSHF8EXSowNDhMzl30jI_.cert.pem`

You may also have to transform the **.pem** file into **.crt** file to be able to add it to your local store.

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in .\edge_owner_azxVrrdEVxd7kvKvne1pOEyuSHF8EXSowNDhMzl30jI_.cert.pem -out .\edge_owner_azxVrrdEVxd7kvKvne1pOEyuSHF8EXSowNDhMzl30jI_.cert.crt
```

Links:

- [How to add a certificate to Windows certificate store](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026808753-How-to-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-on-Windows)
- [Azure IoT Hub certificates - important to know](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp#certificates----important-to-know)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, I believe. As far as I know, the C# SDK relies on the certificate being in the Windows or Linux certificate store. It's mentioned in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-connect-downstream-device?view=iotedge-2018-06&WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#net) as well.

There is [a sample](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/master/samples/dotnet/EdgeDownstreamDevice) where the path to the certificate is provided to the application, which then opens the certificate store and saves the cert to it. I hope this is sufficient for your case!